# My teacher said that I should move the boolean variable into the loop. But I do not understand how to do it

Tags: java, loops, boolean

My code in Java:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Введите целое число: ");
    int n = scanner.nextInt();
    boolean isPrime = false;

    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < i; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                isPrime = false;
                break;
            } else {
                isPrime = true;
            }
        }
        if (isPrime) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

}

But my teacher said that I should move the boolean variable into the loop. This will simplify the code.
But I do not understand how to do it.

Comment: Then ask your teacher again. S/he can provide a much better explanation face-to-face than we can online.

Comment: Why don't you just replace `isPrime = true` with `System.out.println(i);` ? Then you don't need the boolean variable at all.

Comment: @RobertHarvey has the right suggestion, but I think your teacher is suggesting to move `boolean isPrime = false;` just below the `for` loop. That's because the variable is currently used only within that block and it's always a good idea to contain the scope of your variables. Having said that, it's hard to guess exactly what your teacher means, but they're saying you can simplify the code... And Harvey showed you how to do it

Comment: use seive-of-erasthones

Comment: @rishabhagarwal: That's not the real question that is being asked.  See the edit I made to the title.

Comment: @RobertHarvey saw it was edited just now. sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your teacher is saying is that this line:

> boolean isPrime = false;

Needs to be moved into the loop where the comments are.  You are clearly looking for all prime numbers between 2 and n.  Your loop variable 'i' is the prime-number to test, and whether it is prime or not, needs to be initialized to `false` every time you start an iteration test.

```
for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {

    // NEEDS TO BE RIGHT HERE - 
    boolean isPrime = true;
    // You are finding Prime Numbers, and the outer-loop (loop-var 'i')
    // Means the 'isPrime' needs to be re-initialized each time you start testing
    // whether a certain number, i, is prime or not!

    for (int j = 2; j < i; j++)
        if (i % j == 0) { isPrime = false; break; } 

    // and this line needs to be removed completely.
    // else { isPrime = true; }
    if (isPrime) System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: Ha, I didn't even realize that it was buggy because it wasn't getting reinitialized. You really shouldn't have removed braces though, it's best to make the smallest change possible from the original code so it's easy to see what's changed. Also many have linting rules to not allow this style of coding.

Comment: But this code does not become easier. And displays the wrong values.

Comment: @N.Khud so your current code works for all inputs you've tried?

Comment: Works fine!  When I enter 200 for n, the list of prime-numbers less than 200 includes: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97, 101, 103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167, 173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199

Comment: Which looks accurate to me - but I'd have to write a Java Program to test if this list is right... :)

Comment: @Ralph Torello 
Thank you very much! I understood my mistake. I have to be more attentive.